# How can I make recipient_list of send_mail variable?

Tags: python, django, smtp

I am building EC market place with Django.
We have created shop list page and shop details page. Furthermore, I would like to be able to send mail to each shop on the shop's detail page.

However, we do not know how to change send_mail's recipient_list to the mailAddress of each shop when sending mail on the shop details page.

■ view.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import ShopView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from .models import Shop
from .forms import ContactForm

class ShopView(FormMixin, generic.DetailView):

    model = Shop
    form_class = ContactForm

    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'shopSearch/shop_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return 'contact/finish/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

■ model.py

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mailAddress  = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

■ form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    contents = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send_email(self):
        subject = self.cleaned_data['title']
        from_email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        contents = self.cleaned_data['contents']
        message = '\n\ncontens:\n' + contents + '\n\nfrom to:\n' + from_email
        to = <<mailAddress for each shop>>
        send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use send_email with `to`.

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    contents = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send_email(self, to):
        subject = self.cleaned_data['title']
        from_email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        contents = self.cleaned_data['contents']
        message = '\n\ncontens:\n' + contents + '\n\nfrom to:\n' + from_email
        send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to)
```

And pass `to` list from `form_valid()` in view.

```
...
def form_valid(self, form):
    # set to email list for your model
    # maybe you want to this?
    to = [self.object.mailAddress]
    form.send_email(to)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: glad to help you@!